# Windows 7 says Backup Drive is full, but it doesn't appear to be?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I'm using Windows 7, and I keep getting a message that says my Backup drive (D:/) is full.

In My Computer, it shows it as having 8.69 MB open, but I go into the file, and I see four files, the largest of which is less than 2GB (I have a 12.1GB drive). I tried using command prompt to see a directory of files, and I see a bunch of files that read protect.arabic or protect.russian (there's about 30 different languages), don't know if that has to do with anything...

Answer (score 1):

There can be files hidden by Windows. You can go to Control panel, find the personalization catetory and open Folder Options. In this dialog you should be able to find two check boxes, one is "Show hidden files" and the other is "Show protected system files". Check these two and click OK. Then go to D: to find out what files are taking spaces. However, be careful with the files that were previously hidden.

Also, [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) can help you find our what files are taking the disk spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Only  8 MBs free? Sounds full to me.  I try to install Google Chrome on your computer and that will bring your HD to its knees.